# Azure devops pipeline triggers

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a pipeline that gets triggered by other pipeline and should not be able to be queued by itself. I am unable to find a way to do the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated:**

Structure i am looking for is PipelineA triggers PipelineB and waits for PipelineB's completion. If i add a trigger saying start when completed it wont trigger PipelineB since A is technically not complete.

Thanks

Comment: Did you start by looking at the pipelines documentation for available triggers? Are you using Azure DevOps, or are you using on-prem TFS? If on-prem TFS, what version?

Comment: @DanielMann - I am using azure devops. the structure i want is for the being able to trigger the pipeline 2 from 1 and the pipeline 1 is still active and waiting for pipe 2 to finish, so if i say successful it will not work as far as i understand from doc.

Comment: Hi suprasad, any update on this ticket? Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Azure DevOps, you can add a [pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-triggers-1) to run your pipeline upon the successful completion of the triggering pipeline.

To prevent triggering two runs of a pipeline, you must remove its own CI trigger or pipeline trigger.

Comment: the structure i want is for the being able to trigger the pipeline 2 from 1 and the pipeline 1 is still active and waiting for pipe 2 to finish, so if i say successful it will not work as far as i understand from doc.

Comment: Pipeline trigger runs your pipeline B upon the successful completion of the pipeline A, which not meets your requirement. To meet your requirement, you could try to add a [agentless job](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs), add [Invoke REST API task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops) in this job, and [queue a build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) in this task to build pipeline B.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have this build-in feature at present. You need to customize yourself.

Triggering a pipeline can be done via the API and trough PowerShell. You can write your own script file and use the PowerShell tasks.

Then you could use Rest API to query to build result for you have triggered above.

Finally use a task [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic).

> Inside the Control Options of each task, and in the Additional options
>   for a job in a release pipeline, you can specify the conditions under
>   which the task or job will run.

Unless the query result of you trigger build PipelineB is completed/succeed. Then you could continue to run left tasks in Pipeline A

Comment: Thank you. That is how i am doing it now. But i was trying to see if there was a way to disable the queue option on pipeline B and only be triggered by specific triggers.

Comment: Hi @suprasad  It's not able to disable the queue option in Web UI with a pipeline. Unless, you set related permission  "queue builds" to disable a specific user's access to queue the build.  `Can put a build in the queue through the interface for Team Foundation Build or at a command prompt. They can also stop the builds that they have queued. ` More details about permission please take a look at this official link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#build-object-level